# enable to found version for ndiswrapper!

Tags: wireless, usb, ndiswrapper

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386. I have a wire internet C.

I dont have internet in my computer, and well I only have wifi in my house. I use a little USB wifi adapter (TP-Link). I have  installed ndiswrapper with my cd instalation  and I think that I installed well.

The problem is that I cant use it  when I open the console and type ndiswrapper it appears a menssage that said `unable to found a version for ndiswrapper` and I don't know what to do.

What can I do ?

Comment: "i think that i installed well" How or what did you install?

Comment: well i follow tha steps to installed and know i fixed the problem, but now i cant istall my driver it says that DRIVER.INF dosent exist and i haved downl.

Comment: "i follow tha steps" What steps? And please add or edit any information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GUI application for Manage `ndiswrapper` called `ndisgtk`.

So install following :

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-dkms ndiswrapper-source ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

You can install the driver wtth :

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i <DRIVERNAME>.inf
```

**BUT**

TP-Link gives Linux drivers. With NDIS you installs Windows drivers. So search in http://www.tp-link.com/ support section for Linux drivers for your Card. Be pricise for the card name. There are several cards. You can find it by command `lsusb`

Or

You can install them from Official Ubuntu repository by installing following packages.

```
sudo apt-get install collectd-dev collectd-core collectd-dbg jockey-common inux-image-3.2.0-23-generic
```